# Particle System Hangs the Game

Tags: unity, particles

I create a Smoke Effect in my Game Scene using Particle system. it works Perfectly in unity Editor, but when I run Game in Android Device it hangs. I search about that but not getting any right solution. Any one can know how to optimize the particle system and run smoothly in device? thanks in advance.  Here is the Snapshot of Particle system.
      [image]

Comment: Have you tried lowering the max particle to say 100-200? Increase start size if seems low dense.

Comment: yes i will try this and its increase little bit performance. thanks @Sp

Comment: is there any another changes to more smoothness.?

Comment: What shader are your particles using?

Comment: i using Shader Particles/Alpha Blended.

Answer (score 1):

Lower the max particle to 50-100. Increase start size if seems less dense. Also lower the emission rate if works for you. Increase start lifetime if needed.

Answer (score 1):

500 particles is fine for all of the Android devices, the problem can be in texture format used for particle rendering. Also not sure what setup you have in Shape section.

Comment: In Shape Section i used BOX shape.

Comment: This looks like a comment asking for clarification / further details, not an answer to the question.